# Is it possible to do face recognition with just the eyes?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, facial-recognition

Assuming the input photo is focused on a person's face, if the person is wearing a surgical mask, most face recognition software fail to identify the subject's face.

Most facial landmark models are trained to identify at least the eyes and the tip of the nose (for example, dlib's 5 point landmark).

Is it possible to construct a model that is trained to identify a face based on only the eyes?

Comment: Presumably, it's possible, but I don't know what the accuracy will be, and the only way to know will probably to try it, or find someone else who has previously tried it (e.g., find a research paper on the subject).  I believe I've seen reports in news media indicating that some companies have already done this with some success.   The paper you cited in [your past post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133349/755) seems relevant, and you can probably find other related literature through standard literature search techniques (Google search etc.).

Answer (score -1):

Recognising the right face is not the problem. Reliably rejecting the wrong face is.

Comment: Ah I worded the question vaguely, I edited the question, thankyou very much.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer...